# How to prevent the use of Type3 fonts

Tags: fonts, linux, vector, bitmap

I am using pdfTeX v.3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 on Arch linux. This is my relevant preamble.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{titlesec,hyperref,cite,graphicx}
```

All PDFs I compile have bitmapped Type3 fonts. I need vector fonts. I can add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` without success. I have updated the `fontmap`.

According to the bottom of the log I see the fonts used, for example:

> ```
> home/dmt/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmr10.657pk
> ```

and

> ```
> usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr12.pk
> ```

Should I install `cm-super`? Why is it not included in my TeX Live installation? I am uncertain and have been unsuccessful in the process of manually installing it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you include more details from the log (e.g. change to a minimal example, for which you can include the full log file), mention how you installed your TeX distribution, etc.?

Comment: How did you update the fontmap? The Type 1 `cmr` fonts (e.g. `cmr10.pfb`) are part of `texlive-core` if you are using the TeX Live of arch linux. So they should be there. Maybe you should remove (or rename) `/home/dmt/.texlive` to come back to the distribution settings. Note: Don't use `updmap` for updating the fontmaps, use `sudo updmap-sys`.

Comment: Can you report the path of the loaded `pdftex.map`, that you find in the log file?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: *Problem resolved by reinstalling texlive-core.*

THank you for answering (: !
Here is a minimal example.

Doc:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\title{\textbf{Bon Giorno}}
\author{DMT}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Pixels}
Low DPI
\end{document}
```

Log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch
Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)  \write18 enabled. entering
extended mode (/home/dmt/.cache/gummi/gummi_L0UD0Y LaTeX2e
<2016/03/31> patch level 3 Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for
83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class:
article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)) No file
gummi_L0UD0Y.aux.
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(/home/dmt/.cache/gummi/gummi_L0UD0Y.aux) )
</home/dmt/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts /pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmr10.657pk>
</home/dmt/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour /public/cm/cmbx12.720pk>
</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi60 0/cmr12.pk>
</home/dmt/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmbx12.864p k>
Output written on /home/dmt/.cache/gummi/gummi_L0UD0Y.pdf (1 page,
11008 bytes) . Transcript written on
/home/dmt/.cache/gummi/gummi_L0UD0Y.log.
```

PDF:

```
dmt@dmt ~ $pdffonts "Desktop/minimal.pdf"
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       4  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       5  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       6  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       7  0
```

I have renamed /home/dmt/.texlive without success.
My problem persisted so **I reinstalled the texlive-core package and now the cmr fonts are back in place.**

Sorry for not trying that earlier. Thank you for the help